# Creating an Android repository with a github repository

Tags: android, github, implements, jitpack

My library was placed in jitpack, but it cannot be implemented in Android, it gives an error that the address does not exist
erro            implementation 'com.github.dorfaksoft:com.pushstorm:1.7.9'
[image]

content file. txt jitpack
Exit code: 0

✅ Build artifacts:
com.github.dorfaksoft:com.pushstorm:1.7.9

Files:
com/github/.../.../1.7.9
com/github/.../.../1.7.9/build.log
com/github/.../.../1.7.9/...-1.7.9-sources.jar
com/github/.../.../1.7.9/...-1.7.9.pom
com/github/.../.../1.7.9/...-1.7.9.pom.md5
com/github/.../.../1.7.9/...-1.7.9.pom.sha1

Comment: did you add repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
} this  to your project's build.gradle file:

Comment: I did this, the problem is something else

Comment: Did you follow these steps to [publish an Android library](https://jitpack.io/docs/ANDROID/)?